# Multiple partition issues on insert using Hive

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive

I'm creating a table with multiple partitions. I create the table just fine and all appears to be working well, but I cannot insert using my insert code and get the correct response, one it seems the columns on the partition are inverted, or swapped. That means the `event_date` and `stem` are swapped which is very frustrating.

So for example in the partition code in databricks is:

```
%sql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
company_id string
, event_date string
, context_page_url string
, stem string
)
USING parquet partitioned by (event_date, stem);
```

and the insert code is:
`

```
%sql

insert overwrite table table_name partition (event_date, steam)
(
  select cs.company_id as company_id 
  , cs.context_page_url as context_page_url 
  , split_part(cs.context_page_url, '/', 7) as stem
  , try_cast(concat(cs.year, "-", cs.month, "-", cs.day) as string) as event_date
  from cstr_table cs where year=2023 and month = 5 and day = 1 and geo_country_iso = "GB" and context_page_url like "%help%"
)
```

This is not the case if I partition on just the single field: `event_date`.
`

To insert the data in the correct way, with `event_date` reflecting the date, not the `stem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your select along with following modifications.

- Partition column needs to be the last column in select query.
- add the following set command

  ```
  set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
  set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
  ```
- modified insert command is

  ```
   INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_name PARTITION (event_date, steam)
   SELECT cs.company_id as company_id , 
   cs.context_page_url as context_page_url ,
   , try_cast(concat(cs.year, "-", cs.month, "-", cs.day) as string) as 
   event_date,
   , split_part(cs.context_page_url, '/', 7) as stem
   from cstr_table cs where year=2023 and month = 5 and day = 1 and 
   geo_country_iso = "GB" and context_page_url like "%help%"
  ```

Comment: I'm doing this in databricks. does that make a difference to the settings?

Comment: %sql
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict

Comment: Thanks! Is there any smart way to determine whether a double partition is going to allow faster look-up compared to a single look-up.

Comment: Sure . Depends on what type workload . first we can understand on partition concepts . Hive partitioning is generally more advantageous for read-only workloads as it can significantly improve query performance by minimizing the amount of data read. For read-write workloads, the impact of partitioning depends on the specific operations you perform and whether they align with the partitioning strategy you've chosen. It's essential to carefully design your partitioning scheme based on your data and query patterns to maximize its benefits.

Comment: But if your workload more specific on write workload alone you can think of it .